# Azure pipeline yaml: use each command and compare string

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I migrate my classic legacy TaskGroup to Yaml and I struggle with string comparison.
I have 3 stages: dev, test and prod.
My stage *dev* and *test*  must immediately in parallel and *prod* must depends on *test*.

I try to optimize using for each command that i read in multiple articles.

```
trigger:
  - main

parameters:
  - name: environment
    type: object
    default:
    - 'dev'
    - 'test'
    - 'prod'

pool:
  name: local

stages:
  - ${{ each env in parameters.environment }}:
    - stage: ${{env}}
      ${{ if eq( '${{ env }}', 'prod') }}:
        dependsOn: test
      ${{ else }}:
        dependsOn: []
```

As you can see parameter *dependsOn* is empty when *dev* or *test* environement are detected. And when environment *prod* is detected then it must dependsOn *test*.

What i get is that *else* is already triggered whatever environment detected. Did I miss something ? Do I apply correct algorithm ?

Thx for your feedback
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is wrong.  Change `${{ if eq( '${{ env }}', 'prod') }}` to `${{ if eq(env, 'prod') }}`, remembering that the `eq` is already inside a `${{ ... }}` block which applies to everything inside it, including the `env` (so you don't need to add it again.

Full working solution for me:

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
  - name: environment
    type: object
    default:
    - 'dev'
    - 'test'
    - 'prod'

stages:
- ${{ each env in parameters.environment }}:
  - stage: ${{env}}
    ${{ if eq(env, 'prod') }}:
      dependsOn: test
    ${{ else }}:
      dependsOn: []
    jobs:
      - job: SomeJob
        steps:
        - script: echo ${{env}}
```

[image: Azure Pipelines screenshot]

Comment: Thx a lot Andrew for taking time to help me.